# SQL Server - is the value in the passed in parameter array?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

i am tyring to pass in a LIST of values from C# and query it in my stored procedure.

this is what i have:

```
select   distinct FileStream_ID
FROM         dbo.vEmailSent
WHERE     
RequestType_ID in ( + '"' + @RequestTypeID +'"' + )
```

but i'm getting an error on syntax with the parenthesis and without them. please help.

Comment: Can we assume your are using SQL Server 2012?

Comment: If you are using SQL2008 or later you should be using a Table Valued Parameters. SQL 2005, and you care about performance, use a CLR function. Before that, upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `AND` directly after the `WHERE`. But even if you fix that, you need a `Split` function, then this works:

```
WHERE
    ([RequestType_ID] IN
        (SELECT  Item
         FROM    dbo.Split(@RequestTypeID, ',') AS  Split))
```

This is a possible implementation of the table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2008
Using Table-Valued Parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html)

Answer (score 4):

You potentially have a few syntax errors.

First of all, you have an `and` at the start of your `WHERE` clause. Change to:

```
WHERE     
RequestType_ID in ( + '"' + @RequestTypeID +'"' + )
```

---

Secondly, you have `+` at the start & end of the `IN` parenthesis. This is invalid and should be changed to:

```
WHERE
RequestType_ID in ('"' + @RequestTypeID + '"')
```

---

Finally, you shouldn't have `'"'`. If your parameter `@RequestTypeID` is an `int` type, you should `CAST()` to a `varchar` type, rather than wrapping in quote marks:

```
WHERE
RequestType_ID in (CAST(@RequestTypeID as varchar(100))
```

I suspect this is not what you are trying to do though, and that `@RequestTypeID` is actually comma-delimited integers.

In which case, you cannot use this like you are attempting. If `@RequestTypeID = '1,2,3'`, then SQL is going to return records where `RequestType_ID = '1,2,3'`. Therefore 0 results.

Comment: thank you! my parameter is of type int, how can i change it to work correctly? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, you'll need to use a table valued parameter (if you're on SQL Server 2008+), Dynamic SQL, XML, split the string into a table using a function or similar.

MVP Erland Sommarskog has an excellent breakdown of the positives and negatives of each approach, with performance data here:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html